# License Service Android?

Tags: android, service, android-lvl

I am using a license service in one of my application which I got from http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html. It was working fine, when I put my own apk in my phone it will say "This app is not registered, please buy this app in Android Market" which is good. However, today I saw some copy of my application in some forum. When I tried it, it seems the license is not working. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong. I would really appreciate it a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the md5sum of your .apk and the one you found with no license check. If they are different, then chances are, somebody cracked your app to remove the license restrictions.

It's not perfect, but have you read the [obfuscation](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#impl-Obfuscator) guide in the licensing docs?

Comment: Yes I have read it, I already put 20 random numbers, and all that stuffs. Can you give me some advice how to avoid this kind of piracy. I am really worried because I spent a several months trying to finish that app, and they just got it for free. Thanks for your response!

Comment: Unfortunately, once somebody has the apk, there isn't much you can do to prevent it. Obfuscating as much as possible in the license check can help, but as you've found out, that can only go so far. Possibly the best option would be to try to somehow tie the valid license check with content from a remote server, perhaps over SSL - but again, once the apk is in the hands of a cracker, you can't stop them doing anything. I understand your frustration - although I've not released anything for sale yet, I certainly plan to and these issues are ones I will have to consider also.